# Is mysqldump secure

Tags: security, ssh, mysql

I would like to start this discussion about mysqldump security.
With security I'm not speaking about Cron tasks that display password security or password security in any way, instead I'm talink about the security of the command itself.

In my particular case I have setup the command to execute on my home server the cron job with mysqldump and backup my website database on my VPS that I have with 1&1.

So basically the scenario is that my Home PC is backing up remotely the MySQL database on port 3306.
This work correctly but I start making nightmares while sleeping and thinking that maybe could someone listen on port 3306 and get all my data while I'm backing up (with mysqldump) I mean for what I have understanded mysql is not under SSL with port 3306 so anybody could potentially get the backup copy from the database?

I mean it would be possible this scenario:

1. My Home PC start mysqldump task
2. My VPS on 1&1 prepare remotely the sql dump
3. My Home PC receive locally the dump from the remote server

between point 2 and point 3 is possible that someone get a copy of my file?

Thanks in advance for the answers
Marcos

Answer (score 2):

You should not expose port 3306 on your VPS host to the public internet. MySQL's unencrypted port is not secure.

If you're running mysqldump on your VPS host, and only transferring the resulting dump file to your PC, then you can do this securely.

If you can ssh to your VPS, you should be able to use scp too. This gives you the ability to transfer files securely.

Here's a FAQ article about using scp with 1&1. I found this by googling for "*1&1 scp*":

http://faq.1and1.co.uk/server/root_server/linux_recovery/9.html

If you need to run mysqldump on your Home PC and connect remotely to MySQL on the VPS host, you have options:

- Run mysqldump on the PC with SSL connection options.
- Open an port-forwarding ssh tunnel, then run mysqldump on the PC connecting to the forwarded port.
- Run ssh to invoke mysqldump on the VPS, then capture output.  See example in the accepted answer to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/36467/temporary-ssh-tunnel-for-backup-purposes
- Create a VPN and do anything you want because it's all encrypted.

---

Re your comments of 10/11:

> I need to execute the command from home PC to backup the VPS remotely.
>
> I want to ... receive instead the backup file directly so in the VPS should be saved nothing.

Okay, here's what you can do, without exposing port 3306:

```
$ ssh marcos@192.168.1.3 'mysqldump ...options.. | gzip -c' > ~/dump.sql.gz
```

Notice the position of quotes in that command.  You're executing on the VPS the command: `mysqldump ...options.. | gzip -c`.  The stdout of that command is a gzipped stream of the dump.  That stream is returned via ssh, and then `>` saves the output locally in the shell on your PC.

---

Re your comment of 10/13:

> now I'm storing on the server an open text file that contain the credentials to access the MySQL server. I mean if someone will break into the server it will be able not just to damage the server content but also to damage and stolen MySQL database and informations. Am I right?

If you use MySQL 5.6 you can use the new feature to store connection credentials in a semi-encrypted manner.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

If you use MySQL 5.5 or earlier, then you're right, you should be careful to restrict the file permissions of `my.cnf`.  Mode 600 should be enough (i.e. it's not an executable file).

But if someone breaks into your server, they may have broken in with root access, in which case nothing can restrict what files they read.

MySQL doesn't have enough security to block access if someone gains root access, so it's up to you to use other means to prevent breakins.  Firewalls, etc.

Comment: For completeness: MySQL supports SSL encrypted connections. [You can find the docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ssl-connections.html).

Comment: Seconded, **DO NOT** expose port 3306 under any circumstances. Also, it doesn't matter if you're using SSL if MySQL itself develops a security vulnerability. SSH is reasonably bulletproof, so long as you're patched, but I wouldn't trust MySQL the same way. Having the port open is just inviting attacks or DDOS attempts.

Comment: Thank you tadman, After exploring many tutorials I came up assembling this command: [mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf test_dump | gzip -c | ssh marcos@192.168.1.3 'cat > ~/dump.sql.gz'] the problem is that is saving the sql backup on the VPS instead of streaming it over SSH. So locally I don't receive nothing, but if I login on the server I see the backup in the home directory. I want to avoid this and receive instead the backup file directly so in the VPS should be saved nothing. Is that possible? Am I making some mistakes? Thanks Marcos

Comment: tadman, also a question, you wrote before DO NOT expose port 3306, but as I commented at the bottom, if I block port 3306 do you think my website still works? I mean if I disable connection using iptables on port 3306 how my website will recognize the server as MySQL? thanks Marcos.

Comment: @MarcosLamba, do not expose 3306 to the whole internet, but it's okay to configure iptables to allow the application server to connect to port 3306 (or whatever port MySQL listens on).

Comment: @MarcosLamba, if you want to save mysqldump output locally, just skip the ssh step: `mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf test_dump | gzip -c > ~/dump.sql.gz`  This is the beauty of pipelines, they are very modular. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for answers ;-). For 3306 I have few choices since my country ISP doesn't provide static IP for personal DSL line. Maybe instead of using % I can allow just IP from my country? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: @BillKarwin regarding the second question I need to execute the command from home PC to backup the VPS remotely. As I read for precedent answer one of the best way is to do under ssh tunnel to ensure all process is safe. In your suggestion I don't see ssh, probably I didn't explain correctly before? Or I'm wrong? Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks I tried the command above but the result is the following error: marcos@192.168.1.3's password: 
Could not open required defaults file: /marcos/my.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted. - To let you understand I created on my local PC the file my.cnf that contain hostname, name and password of the MySQL database on the VPS. With the command from what I understanded it search for the my.cnf on the VPS instead of the local PC. I could create the file on the VPS but I think is high high risky as the file contain the credentials for the database. Thanks Marcos

Comment: @BillKarwin I forget to paste before my command is the following (executed on local PC): ssh marcos@192.168.1.3 'mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf test_dump | gzip -c' > ~/dump.sql.gz

Comment: That will try to open my.cnf on your VPS server, because it runs the mysqldump command there. Upload your my.cnf to the VPS.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that's exactly what I was thinking but I would like also to make a question about. I'm very worry about security. If before with mysqldump over 3306 was not secure, now I'm storing on the server an open text file that contain the credentials to access the MySQL server. I mean if someone will break into the server it will be able not just to damage the server content but also to damage and stolen MySQL database and informations. Am I right? I also thought that could be an idea to create a backup user on database with limited permissions and save my.cnf with 700 permission.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you very very very much. With your help and other answers I've learned something new ;-). The command work correctly I'm really happy! So I can consider it safe right? I mean I'm receiving data as before but this time under SSH not like before directly over port 3306. So my question is if someone would like to get the data (mysql backup) while is transfered from my VPS to my home PC, he would need to break into SSH right? And I imagine if I constantly update software and password is quite impossible correct or I'm wrong? Thanks again Marcos

Comment: @MarcosLamba, funny you should say that. There are now reports that claim the NSA has the ability to crack ssh or ssl. But these reports are kind of unproven, and the subject of speculation and theoretical extrapolation. Sort of "if anyone could crack ssh with current technology, it's likely to be the NSA." Example: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/09/the_nsas_crypto_1.html

Comment: Not that we have any better option currently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but you don't mention how you gonna fetch that data. If you use ssh/scp (with dedicated user for dumps, IP filtered, auth based on private key with key password) is acceptable and consider as safe in my opinion. Another fast way is be a more secure is to set up VPN. Any else is paranoid level for personal use.

Comment: Thank you Bill and others that answered to this discussion, I have read the links provided.

So basically from what I have understanded my method was wrong and highly risky.. I have a couple of questions let's start from the first.

    If I disable port 3306 I think my webpage would stop working since will look on the VPS for the database and without active port it won't run. I'm wrong?

Comment: Second question is secure to change the port? I know that obscurity is not security, but it will change something? thanks in advance

Comment: stay with mysql on 3306 bind to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Make use of iptables and drop any external traffic to 3306. Add dedicated user (let's say backuper), add to cron job to make periodical dumps of db (or any other data you want to backup as well) and save it in the "backuper" home dir. Now on your local PC (or any other machine you wanna store backups) add cron job with 'scp' to your VPS as backuper to fetch backups. Also you can on VPS add rule to accept login only from your machine.

Comment: Hi kAlmAcetA, thanks for the answer, that's the approach I take at the beginning but I than changed since I think is also a potential security issue to mysqldump the database directly in the VPS and than from my local server retrieve the compressed archive in SSH, I mean I'm leaving the archive there on the VPS, if an attacker should login to the VPS it will have immediately all archives of the Mysql without the worry of bruteforce Mysql passwords. Instead I'm looking on a more secure way to retrieve the mysqldump from the ssh console, I mean ssh the VPS from my local pc, execute mysqldump

Comment: After exploring many tutorials I came up assembling this command:

[mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf test_dump | gzip -c | ssh marcos@192.168.1.3 'cat > ~/dump.sql.gz'] the problem is that is saving the sql backup on the VPS instead of streaming it over SSH. So locally I don't receive nothing, but if I login on the server I see the backup in the home directory. I want to avoid this and receive instead the backup file directly so in the VPS should be saved nothing. Is that possible? Am I making some mistakes? Thanks Marcos